# JMS connection to WebsphereMQ

Tags: jms, ibm-mq

I am trying to connect to `WebsphereMQ` using `JMS`.

The following configuration is defined:

```
properties.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory");
properties.put(Context.URL_PKG_PREFIXES, "com.ibm.ws.naming");
properties.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "iiop://localhost:2809");
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "user")
properties.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, "password")
```

The following dependencies are included in the Maven POM file:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>  
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mqjms</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jmqi</artifactId>
    <version>7.0.1.4</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.ibm</groupId>
  <artifactId>com.ibm.dhbcore</artifactId>
  <version>7.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
   <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
   <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.jar</artifactId>
   <version>7.0.1.4</version>
   <scope>runtime</scope>
</dependency>
```

When trying to instantiate the context (`new InitialContext(properties)`), the following exception is thrown:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.ibm.websphere.naming.WsnInitialContextFactory]
    at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:674)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.getDefaultInitCtx(InitialContext.java:307)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.init(InitialContext.java:242)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.<init>(InitialContext.java:216)
```

Is there a maven dependency missing?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what the maven coordinates are, since I don't think these libraries are in any public repos, so coordinates will be repo specific, but according to [this post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/74068/Websphere/Jars-required-run-stanalone-application), the jar files required are:

- wssec.jar
- naming.jar
- namingclient.jar
- lmproxy.jar
- sas.jar
- ecutils.jar

Comment: Thanks, but that post is twelve years old. Does anyone know the maven dependencies ?

Answer (score 0):

Nicholas' answer is correct. (Moving this from comment to allow for formatting)

IBM does not distribute their jars into Maven repositories. Someone in your organization deployed them manually (which is a common practice).

You either:

1. Are not pointing your maven settings.xml or project pom.xml to your organization's internal Maven Repository
2. Need to deploy the MQ jars to the repository manually.

   mvn deploy:deploy-file -DgroupId=com.ibm.mq -DartifactId=mqjms -Dversion=7.5.0.2 -Dfile=mqjms.jar

See: https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-3rd-party-jars-remote.html

Comment: Thanks, however I have added com.ibm.mqjms as a dependency (see updated question), but the mqjms jar does not contain com.ibm.mq.jms.MQQueueConnectionFactory.

Comment: You need a number of jars, nut just the mqjms.jar